# Matlab and XTickLabel

Tags: matlab, plot, contourf

I've been trying to get Matlab to change the labelling on my contourf plots for about an hour now. When I go to change XTickLabel or XTick, it simply removes my x-axis altogether! The frustrating and infuriating thing is that I'm doing *exactly* what all the [help pages](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html) and [help forums](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/92565-how-do-i-control-axis-tick-labels-limits-and-axes-tick-locations) are asking me to do - I honestly don't understand why this is not working.

Hence, I am here.

My plotting code (knowledge of the function shouldn't be required - the code is rather intense. It is, however, a 2D contourf plot with valid data and ranges - the axes are the issue, not the graph):

```matlab
   contourf(time,f,power,levels)
   colormap(jet(levels))
   set(gca,'XTickLabelMode','manual')
   set(gca, 'XTick', 0:23);
   set(gca, 'XTickLabel', {'0';'1';'23'});
   xlabel('Time (UT)')
   ylabel('Frequency (Hz)')
   caxis([0,8])
   axis([0 StopTime 0 0.1])
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: The plotting is or isn't the issue? ;) Also, it might be worth linking the help page you mentioned.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/92565-how-do-i-control-axis-tick-labels-limits-and-axes-tick-locations

http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html

Neither were much help - as far as I know, I'm doing exactly what they're telling me to!

And the graph itself isn't an issue - it's the axes that I need to change (specifically, the labels/ticks).

Comment: How are you trying to change *XTickLabel or XTick* ? And what do you intend to change it/them to?

Comment: As far as I know (which isn't very far - I'm fairly new to this level of matlab coding), I am changing the axis handler settings of 'Xtick' and 'XTickLabel'. They are currently just holding the values of my arrays (which I don't want).

I want to change my x-axis to UT time - from 0 through to 23, in equal increments (of 1).

Comment: Coulf you please provide us with some sample data for `time`, `f`, `power`, `levels`, for repeatability purposes?

Comment: Not without coping over the entirety of my code, as well as the files I'm reading this information from.

All I need to do it relabel an axis. The information in the graph isn't needed - the graph itself works fine. I just want to relabel the axes.

But this may help: http://i62.tinypic.com/23mm23o.jpg

Comment: You could simply provide truncated versions of these vector/matrices containing 10 data points. This helps us run your code and getting a result that approximates the one you are expecting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved:

I realized that the 'XTick' relied on current values of the array I was using to define the x-axis. I can't just assume matlab will evenly space a new array (at least, if there's a way to do that, I don't know). So, since I have 85,680 data points on my X-axis, I simply rescaled it by:

```
   set(gca, 'XTick', 0:3570:85680)
   set(gca, 'XTickLabel', num2cell(0:24))
```

Moral of the story: Matlab doesn't let you arbitrarily stick a new axis over an old one using these two functions.

Answer (score 1):

You have a final `axis([0 StopTime 0 0.1]))` command which clears your plot, by creating a fresh new axis. That's why all your existing plots are gone. Try removing it:

```matlab
contourf(time,f,power,levels)
colormap(jet(levels))
set(gca,'XTickLabelMode','manual')
set(gca, 'XTick', 0:23);
set(gca, 'XTickLabel', {'0';'1';'23'});
xlabel('Time (UT)')
ylabel('Frequency (Hz)')
caxis([0,8])
```

Now the question becomes: are your ticks sensibly placed for the data you are representing? Without knowing the data I cannot answer this for you. So the ball is in your court now. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use cell arrays to define the `ticks` and `tick-labels` and then use them with `set` function call, to make it more elegant -

```
xtick_label_cellarr = num2cell(0:24)
xtick_cellarr = linspace(0,85680,numel(xtick_label_cellarr))

set(gca, 'XTick',xtick_cellarr)
set(gca, 'XTickLabel',xtick_label_cellarr)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - but it didn't work. As far as I know, what I had previously was equivalent to this.

Comment: @Yoshi Can you share screenshots of what you are getting and what you intend to get?

Comment: @Yoshi Based on your posted solution, suggested a way to keep it a bit more generic I guess.